# Pass an argument to user function for scipy.stats.binned_statistic

Tags: python, scipy

I am using

```
def findT(values, passFraction):
    #...<skipping func body>

def findT90(values):
    return findT(values, 0.9)    

frac90_result = scipy.stats.binned_statistic(m_test, [y_pred], bins=5, range=(0,1),
 statistic=findT90)
```

but I would like to generalize this so that I can pass any other value in place of `0.9` without having to make a new function. How can I include the 
`passFraction` value when calling `scipy.stats.binned_statistic`

Comment: why not call findT directly in binned_statistic function instead of findT90?

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan Because `binned_statistic` can take a function that only accepts 1 argument, but I need to give 2

Comment: do you get any error if you use frac90_result = scipy.stats.binned_statistic(m_test, [y_pred], bins=5, range=(0,1),
 statistic=findT(values, 0.9))

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan that would just create a function call and try to feed the `statistic` argument with the return value of the function `findT`, we want to give it a function, so without `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

binned_statistic only supports single-argument functions. Therefore, either do what you did, or create a needed function on-the-fly:

`binned_statistic(..., statistic=lambda values: findT(values, 0.9))`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. On-the-fly function creation. Thanks!